# How to encode a url in spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, spring-security

greetings all 
I have a post method in a controller, which redirects to a new page
I a way such like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "redirect:http://www.x.appName.com/myPage";

    }
```

suppose that the user already has a session before the redirection
and I want to encode the new url before redirection to maintain the user session
how to do so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass the `HttpServletResponse` as parameter, and use the [`encodeRedirectURL(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeRedirectURL%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
String url = "http://www.x.appName.com/myPage";
url = response.encodeRedirectURL(url);
return "redirect:" + url;
```

But first make sure spring does not do this for you automatically.

Comment: thanks, but i am not sure if spring does this automatically or not, can anyone expert with spring tell us please ?

Comment: "Trying" is a very bad method. It could work one way in the version/setup he uses, and the work differently on another (like in production).

Comment: A lot of time has passed since this answer, Now do you any information about whether Spring (Security) does it automatically or not ?

Comment: I don't know :) if you investigate and have an answer, let us know

Answer (score 1):

UriComponentsBuilder's build method defaults to "false" which will then trigger the encoding:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).build().toString()
```

Comment: Depending on defaults is risky, better/safer to code explicitly. No guarantees that default won't change in some future release.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doc is the ultimate resource for questions like this. Additionally you could download code of the right version from github, and debug for an answer. As for the question, check here http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix, or check the source code of class RedirectView below(applicable to spring 4.1.0):

```
    protected void appendQueryProperties(StringBuilder targetUrl, Map<String, Object> model, String encodingScheme)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    // Extract anchor fragment, if any.
    String fragment = null;
    int anchorIndex = targetUrl.indexOf("#");
    if (anchorIndex > -1) {
        fragment = targetUrl.substring(anchorIndex);
        targetUrl.delete(anchorIndex, targetUrl.length());
    }

    // If there aren't already some parameters, we need a "?".
    boolean first = (targetUrl.toString().indexOf('?') < 0);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : queryProperties(model).entrySet()) {
        Object rawValue = entry.getValue();
        Iterator<Object> valueIter;
        if (rawValue != null && rawValue.getClass().isArray()) {
            valueIter = Arrays.asList(ObjectUtils.toObjectArray(rawValue)).iterator();
        }
        else if (rawValue instanceof Collection) {
            valueIter = ((Collection<Object>) rawValue).iterator();
        }
        else {
            valueIter = Collections.singleton(rawValue).iterator();
        }
        while (valueIter.hasNext()) {
            Object value = valueIter.next();
            if (first) {
                targetUrl.append('?');
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                targetUrl.append('&');
            }
            String encodedKey = urlEncode(entry.getKey(), encodingScheme);
            String encodedValue = (value != null ? urlEncode(value.toString(), encodingScheme) : "");
            targetUrl.append(encodedKey).append('=').append(encodedValue);
        }
    }

    // Append anchor fragment, if any, to end of URL.
    if (fragment != null) {
        targetUrl.append(fragment);
    }
}
```

In short, Spring does it for you if you know where to put the values.